# how to build c++ thrift library for hypertable

Tags: c++, hypertable

i am new to hypertable and i need to know how can i build an c++ client library to integrate hypertable in my cpp program

Answer (score 0):

it is already written in c++. All you need to do is to compile it and link as library.

There are already some examples how to use it: https://github.com/nuggetwheat/hypertable/tree